# Value of type uiview has no member size

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have error:
Value of type uiview has no member size. Here is my code:

```
if let nv = (AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController) {

        let pushedViewControllers = nv.viewControllers
        let presentedViewController:UIViewController = pushedViewControllers[pushedViewControllers.count - 1]
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(presentedViewController.view.size()) //HERE IS THE ERROR
```

Checked the h file, UIViewController has public var view: UIView!
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with `size()`, not `view`. It should be `view.bounds.size`

> Value of type uiview has no member size

This is saying that UIView instances have no `size` method or property. Which is true.

Comment: Thank you so much!